# Why is there an & before $input in array_splice ( array &$input , int $offset [, int $length = 0 [, mixed $replacement ]] )

Tags: php, arrays

```
array array_splice  ( array &$input  , int $offset  [, int $length = 0  [, mixed $replacement  ]] )
```

Why is there an & before $input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means the $input array is passed by reference, so any changes made in the function affect that array.  The default behaviour is to pass a copy, so changes made inside the function don't affect the original.

Answer (score 2):

The & indicates that this is a reference, i.e. the array is not copied and any changes to `input` made by `array_splice` will be reflected in the input array. See [the PHP reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) for more details.